# Finding Specific Patterns in Data

Tags: neural-networks

I'm trying to research modeling that can help me find very specific patterns in data.  I've done a fair amount of work about generalized predictions with machine learning, but I'm very confused about how to approach something that gets into very specific predictions.

As an example, for an IT infrastructure that has 1000 Cisco Router across the world.  I'm trying to find patterns in this data when outages occur.  Outages typically are either power related on transport circuit related.  I have historical data for over a year.  I'm trying build a model to help predict the outage type.  But, I want it to have very specific knowledge of previous outages.  Maybe there is a pattern when Routers 17,245 and 813 fail it is always a power problem at each of the sites.

I will have input data about geospacial, diagnostics, and other IT type information.

I know a lot of modeling can generalize this type of scenario, but I'm trying to see if there are options to remember more specific patterns within a large dataset.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you have "labels" or not in your training data, i.e. is your data labelled with "this input $i$ is of type X", "this input $j$ is of type $Y$", etc., or you have only inputs without labels? In the second case, you may consider unsupervised learning? If that's not what you're looking for, can you please clarify why typical clustering algorithms are not suitable for your use case?